# Grouped Boxplots by Categorical Variable

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot, pandas-groupby

Using a pandas for a large dataset which I have already reduced down to the info I need. Basically I would like to plot the distribution of number of friends for users from two different countries as side-by-side boxplots (what I'm referring to as grouped boxplots), by number of hashtags used in their post (range from 1-6, I'm treating this as a categorical variable). This results in a total of 2*6=12 boxplots all in the same frame for easy comparison.

I've done some research and I'm aware of df.boxplot(by='x'), but this doesn't account for the extra level of comparing the two countries.

The dataset has columns for number of hashtags (int), country (string), number of friends (int).

It's good to note that I'm fairly new to graphing in Python, including things like axes and subplots, so please include some extra info in your answer if possible.

Edit: small sample of dataset

```
       #followers  #friends  #mentions  #hashtags  country  lang_user place  
450            53        71          1          0       ja         es   NaN  
489            54        34          1          1       ja         es   NaN  
867          1569      1999          0          0       en         es   NaN  
1021          224       242          0          3       ja         ja   NaN  
1022          377       506          1          5       ja         ja   NaN  
1023          315       305          0          2       ja         ja   NaN
```

Comment: It would be great if you could add a small sample dataset to your question!

Comment: Sure! I'll update now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like using seaborn for this kind of visualizations.
I guessthe "extra level" you mean is called **"hue".**

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",              
data=tips, palette="Set3")
```

and the result would be:
[image]

check out this documentation:
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html

Comment: Seaborn seems to always be the answer! Know of any easy way to display the N values (number of observations) for each plot?

Comment: Any idea on how to do it in matplotlib? The figures of my article are all generated with matplotlib, so I would like that my boxplot use the same library in order that it looks homogeneous.